# How to successfully decrypt AES-256 encrypted content generated with OpenSSL in Node.js using CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptojs

## Context

I have a Node.js AWS Lambda function, which is acting as a custom authorizer and being triggered by AWS API Gateway, that is supposed to take a token from the Authorization header, which is an AES-256 encrypted JSON, and decrypt it using CryptoJS and a secret passphrase. Just FYI, the token is not a JWT.
I've followed [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability) docs but it's just not working. I've read dozens of posts and articles and it's really surprising to me that I haven't been able to find anyone trying a simple approach like mine.

## Steps and Code

1) I have a file called *token.json* containing a stringified JSON object:

```
"{"user_id":1,"name":"user","time":"2019-09-27 13:58:22","env":"dev"}"
```

2) Following CryptoJS examples, in the terminal I'm executing:
`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in token.json -out encrypted-json-token -pass pass:"password" -e -A -base64`

I'm using the `-A` option to get a one line string.
According to `openssl enc --help`:

> -A                  Used with -[base64|a] to specify base64 buffer as a single line

3) I'm taking that output, the encrypted token, and sending it as the value for the `Authorization` header in a HTTP request that's  parsed by AWS API Gateway, which takes that header and passes it to my Lambda function.

4) In the Lambda function:

```
const AES = require('crypto-js/aes');
const Utf8 = require('crypto-js/enc-utf8');

module.exports.authenticate = function authenticate(event, context, callback) {
...
  try {
    const token = event.authorizationToken;
    const decryptedToken = AES.decrypt(token, 'password').toString(Utf8);
    const parsedToken = JSON.parse(decryptedToken);
  }
  catch(error){
  // log error
  }
...
}
```

The result of the decryption is an empty string, and hence parsing to JSON fails.

## Final notes

I'm calling `.toString(Utf8)` since according to [this](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-hashing-output) and [this](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output), the output of a decryption operation is a *Word Array object*, and I need to turn it back to it's original string form, which is supposed to be the stringified JSON token.
Also, I'm testing all this using Serverless offline plugin to emulate API Gateway locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR**: Pass an actual AES key encoded as hex using the `-K` flag.

If you read the [documentation for `openssl enc`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/enc.html) carefully you'll notice there is a difference between the `-pass` (`-k`) and `-K` flags - the first is literally a password, the second is an actual key.

If you use `-pass`, you're actually passing in an arbitrary string password that gets fed through an (obsolete and insecure) KDF, `EVP_KDF`.  If you use `-K`, you can pass a real AES key as a hex string.

Since `EVP_KDF` is insecure, I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It sort of pointed me to the right direction. The problem now is, OpenSSL doesn't allow to *just* pass `-K` option and a hex-encoded key; you also need to pass a hex-encoded IV. For what I known, that IV is actually part of the final ciphertext, so it shouldn't be required to store it along with the key, but if I don't specify the IV when encrypting something with openssl and then decrypting it in Node.js, then there's some pre-pended ciphered text that is not correctly decrypted. So, should I or should I not store the IV when ecrypting something for later decryption?

Comment: An IV isn't secret - it is completely safe to store with the ciphertext and pass over insecure channels.  The only requirement is that you use a new IV for each encryption operation and that it is **not predictable**.  The standard approach is to randomly generate one, use it for encryption, then prepend it to the ciphertext for use during decryption.